# How to create a list of anonymous functions/delegates C#

Tags: c#, list, delegates, func

I have a list object like so

```
        private List<Func<int, double, char, string, string>> FuncList;
```

And have been attempting to add items to this list using delegates and anonymous functions. The problem is, when I attempt to make a function that has this type, I must return a function from that function. I'm managed to do this recursively, but this throws it into an infinite loop. Is it possible to add functions to this list, and if so how?

I'm attempting to add functions that are passed into a delegate like so

```
public delegate Func<int, double, char, string, string> funcDelegate(someFunc);
```

And then do something like this

```
FuncList.add(funcDelegate);
```

How would you write someFunc so that this code would work.

My failed attempt at writing a function that returns the correct type is like so, this does not work as it's recursive with no stopping case.

```
public Func<int, double, char, string, string> SomeFunc(int i, double d, char c, string s1, string s2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i}\n{d}\n{c}\n{s1}\n{s2}");
        return this.SomeFunc(i,d,c,s1,s2);
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is unclear. Please add more code.

Comment: There is no anonymous functions/delegates in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your method doesn't have the right signature.  The last generic parameter in `Func<>` is the return type.  `Action<>` is a generic delegate type that returns void.

Second, the whole point of using `Func<>` is that you DON'T need to create new types of delegates - `Func<>` is already a delegate.

Here's an example:

```
    // A list of delegates that accept an integer and return a string
    private static List<Func<int, string>> delegateList = new List<Func<int, string>>();

    public static string Foo(int x)
    {
        return $"Foo {x}";
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        delegateList.Add(Foo); // Add a delegate to a named method
        delegateList.Add(delegate(int x) { return $"Bar {x * 2}"; } ); // Add a delegate to an anonymous method
        delegateList.Add(x => $"Baz {x * 3}"); // Add a delegate to a lambda
        foreach (var del in delegateList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(del(23));
        }
    }
```

In your example, you are declaring a delegate to a function that returns another delegate, but that doesn't seem to be what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Awesome thanks! This helped make it clear what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my two cent's worth - it handles arbitrary delegates with up to 4 input parameters, but can be extended ...

```
public class so40645583
{
    private IList<Delegate> FuncList = new List<Delegate>();

    public void Add<InputType, OutputType>(Func<InputType, OutputType> func)
    {
        FuncList.Add(func);
    }

    public void Add<InT1, InT2, OutputType>(Func<InT1, InT2, OutputType> func)
    {
        FuncList.Add(func);
    }

    public void Add<InT1, InT2, InT3, OutputType>(Func<InT1, InT2, InT3, OutputType> func)
    {
        FuncList.Add(func);
    }

    public void Add<InT1, InT2, InT3, InT4, OutputType>(Func<InT1, InT2, InT3, InT4, OutputType> func)
    {
        FuncList.Add(func);
    }

    // This won't work as it is trying to return a delegate type
    // public static Func<int, double, char, string, string> SomeFunc(int i, double d, char c, string s1)

    public static string SomeFunc(int i, double d, char c, string s1)
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", i, d, c, s1);
    }

    public static string SomeFunc2(int i)
    {
        return i.ToString();
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        Add<int, double, char, string, string>(SomeFunc);
        Add<int, string>(SomeFunc2);

        // Try invoking via list
        Delegate d = FuncList[0];
        string s = (string)d.DynamicInvoke(2, 2.0, 'c', "Hi");
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        // Invoke directly
        s = SomeFunc(2, 2.0, 'c', "Hi");
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        // Now the second one
        d = FuncList[1];
        s = (string)d.DynamicInvoke(5);
        Console.WriteLine(s);

    }
}
```

To run the test:

```
var so = new so40645583();
so.Test();
```